# Opening up an .ipa file - Piracy

Tags: ios, xcode, piracy

How easy is it to open up an app submitted to Apple's store?

I'm going to submit a new app to the store soon, and want to protect the app file from being opened up to the source-code. So for instance, if I were to download my own app, how easy would it be to pull out all the .h and .m files and recreate it in Xcode?

Does Apple encrypt it somehow?

What steps can I take to mitigate the code being viewed?

EDIT: Allow me to rephrase the question a little better - can I take decompiled code and make it human-readable?

Comment: Have you searched google for answers to these questions?

Comment: @Wain I like google, but when it comes to seeking technical answers from other developers, I prefer calling on the stack community. Even more so than the apple community.

Comment: Are you aware that **compiling** your program before submitting it to Apple "converts" your source code (.h, .m) to machine bytecode, and the source code is no longer included in what you send to Apple?

Comment: Is it a one way system from source code to machine bytecode? No way of reconstructing the original code? If not great, I just don't want people looking at my source code.

Comment: It's pertinent to ask why you don't want people looking at your source. If you think that this makes things like passwords, and access tokens secure, you're incorrect. These things can be dumped out of the binary by tools.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+ios+decompile

Comment: @Wain alright mate, no need to get all sarky. Good google searches always bring me back here anyway ;)

Comment: My motive is simply to have people search for existing answers before posting duplicate questions. It's also faster for you to find an existing answer than to get a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IPA is just a zip. But you don't even need to access the IPA.
Just get iExplorer and access all available assets of your installed apps from your Mac.

The m files however build a compiled binary and can not be read (if you consider de-compiled code as not readable, as I do)

Comment: I use iExplorer and can see all the non-compiled files, like any bundled PDFs etc, but the bit I'm interested in is the compiled binary. Let's say we decompile it (I wouldn't know how) how easy would it be to pull out e.g. the AppDelegate.m file and make it human-readable? I'm assuming our black-hat friends can do this, am I right?

Comment: The interface is still readable, thats required for dynamic access of methods. The rest can of course be reverse engineered, though  the effort is questionable. But you are right if your point is that this is not a secure place to hide your secrets ...

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the answer, it is possible to decompile the binary, but the only thing that would be directly removable from the binary itself would be the headers (or to my knowledge of what I've seen). Then the application would be reverse engineered from there. That would probably be the only thing I'd be worried about when it comes to people stealing my code.